# Benefits of Static Functions for Class Constructions

Tags: c++, constructor

I have seen code like this, so I'm trying to find the reason.
What's the main reason for having static functions that act as constructors, instead of having actual constructors?

I mean something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    static MyClass CreateFrom( bar );
    static MyClass CreateFrom( foo );
    ...
}
```

instead of:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass( bar );
    MyClass( foo );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called the "named constructor idiom".

It's typically used when:

1. You have a lot of ctors with similar enough enough parameter lists that overloaded ctors would be confusing (e.g., different mixtures of integer and floating point numbers, so `1, 1.0, 1` is supposed to mean something different from `1, 1, 1.0`).
2. You have two different sources that both provide the input as the same type. For example, let's assume you wanted to convert a distance on the surface of the earth into the angle subtended between points that distance apart -- but you might want to supply the distance in either miles or kilometers, either of which would be represented as a `double`.

In this case a single `angle(double dist)` can't distinguish between input in kilometer vs. miles, but: `angle_from_miles` and `angle_from_kilomters` can do that quite easily.

Comment: For a concrete example, I have used it in a `Duration` class: `Duration::Days`, `Duration::Hours`, `Duration::Minutes` ... all take the same argument, and it makes it clear what its unit should be when received.

Comment: Also useful when using `enable_shared_from_this`. http://mortoray.com/2013/08/02/safely-using-enable_shared_from_this/

Answer (score 7):

They are called `Named Constructors`.

The are basically used when you want to construct an object which requires to pass a particular set of parameters but internally you need to construct the object differently.

For example you have a class like:

```
class AREA
{
double area;
AREA(int x);
};

//how will you construct the object differently in case of circle and square??
```

For this purpose, we have named constructors which help to create a relevant object.

So we may create 2 static methods inside the class as:

```
static AREA square(int x)
{ return AREA(x*x); }
```

and

```
static AREA circle(int x)
{ return AREA(x*x*3.14); } //or a more accurate PI value
```

Thus, we may call the relevant static function to return the object initialized with the required area.

**NOTE:** These are static as while creating an object for a particular class you shouldn't be requiring an object to do so.

Check **[THIS](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html)** for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious benefits are:

- It's easy to specify the implementation which constructs the instance at the callsite, when multiple constructors are provided. This makes it easier for the class to provide multiple variants.
- These variants may also have different names, but identical parameter lists (or parameter lists which the compiler may call out as ambiguous when determining which to choose).
- It helps you because you can read which constructor your implementation calls -- at the callsite.

Another reason is that it is easier in some cases to initialize the class within a function body, rather than using an initialization list.